# Changing exposed filter doesn't rebuild SQL query

Tags: 7, views, database

I created 5 fields for filters. 3 of them are exposed to site visitor. Problem is that if I even change this exposed filter values while editing View it doesn't rebuild SQL query.
Views version: 7.x-3.3
[exposed_filter_problems](http://www.screencast.com/t/nm1FK43FYuk)
Other 2 exposed to visitors filter have the same settings but different names.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of fight with exposed filter I found my problem. I used drupal administration in Opera. After moving to Chrome everything works great.